# How to generate a file for resin printing from layer by layer images?

Tags: slicing, resin

I would like to print an object on an Elegoo Mars 3, object which is generated layer by layer via other means.

So as input I have a series of BMP or PNG black and white images, one for layer, and I need to somehow assemble them to obtain a CTB printable file.

The solution can either involve generating a 3D model to be loaded in Chitubox, or it can involve generating directly a CTB file.

How can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the open-source tool [UVtools](https://github.com/sn4k3/UVtools). I don't know if there is a built-in method but you can certainly achieve it by writing a short script.

If you don't find the option in the menu, you can ask in the [forum](https://github.com/sn4k3/UVtools/discussions). Tiago, the father of UVTools, is a very kind and knowledgeable person.